Magento 2 custom field not saving it's value in page builder
I am following below link to add custom field in page builder image element only.
How to use custom field in the HTML of Magento 2 pagebuilder?
But it's not saving the value. When I click on the save button and the page reloads, it shows an empty field.
How can I save its value?
Thanks in advance

Here, I am sharing the solution for those who may be facing the same issue.
According to my requirements, I need to add custom fields for height and width in the image element. When we create any page with the page builder, it does not provide an option to set the image height and width. When we check the page performance, it indicates that we need to set explicit height and width for an image.
To resolve this issue, I have added height and width fields to the image element using the following steps.
Step 1: Create custom module.
Step 2: Create file image.xml under
app/code/vendor/module/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_PageBuilder:etc/content_type.xsd">
    <type name="image">
        <appearances>
            <appearance name="full-width"
                        preview_template="Magento_PageBuilder/content-type/image/full-width/preview"
                        master_template="Magento_PageBuilder/content-type/image/full-width/master">
                <elements>
                    <element name="image_dimension">
                        <attribute name="image_width" source="width"/>
                        <attribute name="image_height" source="height"/>
                    </element>
                </elements>
            </appearance>
        </appearances>
    </type>
</config>

Step 3 : Create file pagebuilder_image_form.xml under app/code/vendor/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="seo">
        <field name="image_width" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Image Width</label>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="image_height" sortOrder="31" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Image Height</label>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
        </field>        
    </fieldset>
</form>

Step 5 : Run below command
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento static:content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
Note: In the image.xml file, the "source" attribute is where we need to specify the element. To set the height and width of the image, I have used source="height" and source="width" respectively.
